# What causes loading of external module to fail when `.js` is missing on imports?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I am getting a bunch of these because my imports in an external library didn't always include `.js` in them:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@termsurf+task@0.0.58_@termsurf+task-host@0.0.3_eslint-plugin-import@2.29.1/node_modules/@termsurf/task/host/code/action/convert/document/handler' imported from /home/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@termsurf+task@0.0.58_@termsurf+task-host@0.0.3_eslint-plugin-import@2.29.1/node_modules/@termsurf/task/host/code/tool/node/command.js
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:264:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:917:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1130:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36)
```

I am running this above thing using `pnpm` inside of a docker container, using [`pm2`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for Node.js, which might be relevant.

I have `library-a` which has a bunch of mixed imports like this:

```js
// index.js
import foo from './foo'
import bar from './bar.js'
import baz from './baz/index.js'
```

I then import this `library-a` into `app-b`, and do an `import liba from 'library-a'`, and it fails because of `./foo` not having the `.js` on it.

Both `library-a` and `app-b` have `"type": "module"` in the package.json. The `app-b` `tsconfig.json` is like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "outDir": "host",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": false,
    "noErrorTruncation": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["*.ts", "./**/*.ts", "*.d.ts", "declare.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "host", "tmp", "test"]
}
```

Why would that be happening?

I compile `library-a` with `tsc`, and it doesn't seem to have a problem itself with `./foo`. So I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Comment: What causes it _is_ the missing `.js`.

Comment: But it often works without adding the `.js` which is why I'm confused why it's not working in this specific case.